# I would like to click on a div tag that contains multiple classes

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have my html page (I clicked on inspect element) like below. I would like to click on "Reports - View / Run"
Can you help me out with the VBA code please.

Changed brackets intentionally here to show it better to you!

( div class="nav-favorite-title ng-binding nav-favorite-FILE" ng-class="'nav-favorite-' + favorite.type">Reports - View / Run

Regards,
Uday

Comment: What are you struggling with in Excel-VBA? Navigating to the page? You want it to automatically click on the reports when you visit the page? What code have you got so far?

Comment: Hi Jam, I have written code until it takes me to the correct page. Now I would like to click on "Reports - View / Run" that appears on the left had side of the screen.

Comment: Hi Jam, PFB, Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("google.com")
    While .Busy: DoEvents: Wend
    
    Do Until ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

******************** Here I need to click on the reports...
    
End With

MsgBox ("Process completed")

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
IE.Document.getElementById("X").getElementsByTagName("Y")(0).Click
```

Where X and Y are something to do with your button ID's... Inserted in to your code, which for reference I have created properly below

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("google.com")

While .Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Do Until ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")) ' Here I need to click on the reports...

End With
MsgBox ("Process completed")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. i dont have a button ID. Given div tag was written inside a <a /> tag

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for my question. I used below lines.

Set ElementCol = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each link In ElementCol
    If link.innerHTML = "Reports - View / Run" Then
        link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next link